# MySql: Index loop

Tags: php, mysql

**Problem**
I have a MySql table with x rows where each row as a unique Id. I want to give each of my users a chunk of 10 rows. When a user has read each rows content he clicks 'Next' and I return him the next chunk of 10 rows (`WHERE Id BETWEEN StartIndex AND StartIndex + 9`). This works fine until the chunk overlaps the table. How can I efficiently start again from the start?

**My (not so great) Solution**
Getting the total count:

```
$result = $connection->query("SELECT count(Id) AS num_rows FROM Uris");
$count = $result->fetch_assoc()["num_rows"];
```

And then some if-logic to check if it overlaps (pseudo code):

```
if (StartIndex + 10 >= count)
   makeTwoMySqlCalls(BETWEEN StartIndex AND count-1, BETWEEN 0 AND 10-count-StartIndex)
```

Is there a better (faster) way to do this?

PS: Sorry for the title, don't know what to call this problem.

Comment: it's not a correct db structure. Instead of it create  two tables user and user_data. in user_data you can add as much row as much possible per user and at the time of fetching data you can use `JOIN` query to get record

Comment: use an offset. `select * from uris limit 10 offset 0;` the first time, offset 10 the next time. just pass a `page` var. `$offset = (10 * $page) - 10;` example, page 2 would be 2 * 10 (20 records ), - 10 (which makes offset 10)

Comment: *"How can I efficiently start again from the start?"* - Why would you want that, how should a user know that he's done? I think there is no built-in way to do this properly, but you could use a `union all` block to append the table to itself and deal with the overlap that way. But you'd still need to know the number of rows, so you can go back to 0 after you've passed that point.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `LIMIT` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM the_table WHERE `id` >= start_id LIMIT 10
```

This will fetch up to 10 rows starting from the `id` with value `start_id`.

You have to manage to place the `start_id` as a value into the query, use a prepared statement.

Count the rows you get, if they are less than 10 you reached the last page.

If they are 0 you reached the last page at the previous iteration.